# polynomials with numbers and matrices entries

Tags: matrices, polynomials, unit-of-measure

I found somewhere in a book, that it is defined the polynomial $p\in\mathbb C[X]$ with k degree and then they write down the polynomial for 2 values: $A\in M_n$ and $a\in\mathbb C$, like this:

> $p(A)=a_0*I_n+a_1*a+...+a_k*A^k$ 
>   $p(a)=a_0+a_1*a+...+a_k*a^k$
>   What I don't get is why the coefficient of 0-degreed indeterminate change ( from a_0*I_n to a_0*1), or is it considered a s change? If not, then how should see this transformation? Perhaps it has something to do with the generalized way $X^0$ is viewed in a polynomial, where $X$ is indeterminate? If so, then why is it considered to be correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's $a_0 + A$? (How would you like to add matrices and real numbers?) The identity is added in to make the evaluation possible. I suppose in a sense you can think of it as enforcing $X^0$ to be the identity in the ring which the element you are substituting for $X$ belongs to?

Comment: If you write the "constant" term of your polynomial is $a_0 x^0$, then generalizing from real $x$ (where $x^0 = 1$) to matrix values for the argument, you merely need to define $A^0$ where $A$ is a matrix. The obvious choice (seeking analogy with real numbers) is that $A^0$ should be the multiplicative identity for matrix multiplication (i.e., the identity matrix $I$), so that $A^k A^p = A^{k+p}$ will continue to hold to the degree possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given a polynomial $$p(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$ for a real variable $x$ the value of the polynomial $p$ at a matrix $A$ is defined as $$p(A)=a_nA^n+\ldots+a_1A+a_0I_n.$$ Otherwise, you cannot add number $a_0$ to matrices. This is just how it is defined.